# Why does Lua prohibit goto over a local var definition?

Tags: lua

I read this from the manual http://lua-users.org/wiki/GotoStatement

I have a similar code block in a loop:

```
while true do
  if someCond == nil then
      goto f  -- invalid (forward jump into scope of local definition)
  end

  local x = 1
   -- do something with x
  ::f::
end
```

This will fail with "...jumps into the scope of local x"

But why? if the jump is executed its after any usage of local x - it is not touched anymore - hence "local x" is not required anymore here

When i switch local x with just x = 1 (making in global) it works fine.

Is that an oversight or an optimization that is missing ? E.g. maybe they always assume that a local var could possible be used after jumping to the label

Comment: You can always use a `do`-block to restrict the scope of that local if it truly doesn't need to be used anymore where the label is.

Comment: can you clarify this with a code sample?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how locals are registered, but they're referenced via a numeric index. Presumably if one were to use a `goto` to skip past a local definition, then the local would never be created, and therefore anyone trying to access the local after the label would be attempting to use an invalid index.

You are right that in theory, if the local is never used after the label, then it doesn't necessarily have to prevent the jump, but in practice, a lua local exists until the end of its scope, rather than dying after its last usage. Any sort of dynamic code execution requires this to be true.

However, you can use a `do`-block to restrict the scope of your locals. With your code, you would rewrite this as

```
while true do
  if someCond == nil then
      goto f
  end

  do
      local x = 1
       -- do something with x
  end -- x is now gone
  ::f::
end
```

Comment: thats a neat trick! thanks - i gather for lua 5.3 this could be optimized - another workaround i found is, just declare my local before the goto label and set it as local x = 0 or whatever

Comment: Or just `local x`, which will default it to `nil`. Anyway, Lua 5.1 came out in 2006, and 5.2 in 2011. So don't hold your breath waiting for Lua 5.3 ;)

Comment: @Steve: "*i gather for lua 5.3 this could be optimized*" I would be against such a thing. Lua requires that a local can be accessed any time it is in scope. Scope ends at the end of the block. So what you have is a situation where the code might be legal for a while, then someone tries to access the local later on after the label. Which suddenly invalidates the code. That's no a good thing.

Comment: how could the local be accessed after that if the while block either ends or repeats again ? its not possible

Comment: @Steve: The label is inside of the while block, which means that the local is still alive at the point where the label exists. It doesn't matter that there's nothing after the label.

Comment: "It doesn't matter that there's nothing after the label" i disagree - the lua parser could be well aware of the fact that the local is only used outside of the scope of the goto label e.g. no conflicting access to the local ever - the do ... end workaround is basically just the same - it could already been done by the lua parser as an optimization if it detects this usecase

Comment: @Steve: This would lead to unpredictable behavior. Adding a line of code after the label *should not* suddenly make the existing goto illegal.