# Attempt to "go back" without goto statement

Tags: performance, optimization, lua, goto

The code examples are gonna be in Lua, but the question is rather general - it's **just an example.**

```
for k=0,100 do

    ::again::
    local X = math.random(100)

    if X <= 30 
    then
    -- do something
    else
        goto again       
    end

end
```

This code generates 100 pseudorandom numbers between 0-30. It should do it between 0-100, but doesn't let the loop go on if any of them is larger than 30.

I try to do this task without goto statement.

```
for k=0,100 do

    local X = 100 -- may be put behind "for", in some cases, the matter is that we need an 'X' variable

    while X >= 30 do --IMPORTANT! it's the opposite operation of the "if" condition above!

        X = math.random(100)

    end

    -- do the same "something" as in the condition above


end
```

Instead, this program runs the random number generation until I get a desired value. In general, I put all the codes here that was between the main loop and the condition in the first example.

Theoretically, it does the same as the first example, only without `goto`s. However, I'm not sure in it.

Main question: are these program codes equal? They do the same? If yes, which is the faster (=more optimized)? If no, what's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bad practice to use Goto. Please see http://xkcd.com/292/

Anyway, I'm not much into Lua, but this looks simple enough;

For your first code: What you are doing is starting a loop to repeat 100 times. In the loop you make a random number between 0 and 100. If this number is less than or equal to 30, you do something with it. If this number is greater than 30, you actually throw it away and get another random number. This continues until you have 100 random numbers which will ALL be less than or equal to thirty.

The second code says: Start a loop from 0 to 100. Then you set X to be 100. Then you start another loop with this condition: As long as X is greater than 30, keep randomizing X. Only when X is less than 30 will your code exit and perform some action. When it has performed that action 100 times, the program ends.

Sure, both codes do the same thing, but the first one uses a goto - which is bad practice regardless of efficiency.

The second code uses loops, but is still not efficient - there are 2 levels of loops - and one is based on psuedo-random generation which can be extremely inefficient (maybe the CPU generates only numbers between 30-100 for a trillion iterations?) Then things get very slow. But this is also true for you're first piece of code - it has a 'loop' that is based on psuedo-random number generation.

TLDR; strictly speaking about efficiency, I do not see one of those being more efficient than the other. I could be wrong but it seems the same things is going on.

Comment: So they do the same (most certainly) and both can be slow. Thanks! Also thanks for talking about `goto`, I've heard about it several times before but never was clear, why should I use it cautionly.

Comment: The goto bit needs a little more nuance. Machine language is full of them, in the form of jump insructions. Some of the things programmers are taught so as to avoid goto are only disguised goto, like the finite-state-machine pattern. Goto isn't bad. People who abuse gotos are bad :) That said, they *are* really easy to abuse.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Yes, you are correct. usually placing one goto can be essentially harmless if you understand what is going on. The classic problem that I've seen is that when you place one and it works, you are lulled into using more - this results in a second and third goto. Then more. This pattern results in horrible spaghetti code that becomes quickly unreadable - and usually because of that, someone places a goto in the wrong place and if it breaks, trying to find out why is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use math.random(lower, upper)

```
for k=0,100 do
local X = math.random(0, 30)
end
```

even faster.

Comment: I know, but it was just an example. I may put anything there, with any conditions. I want to know that is this second code might be a good alternative instead of `goto`s.

Answer (score 0):

As I see this pieces of code do the same, but using `goto` always isn't the best choice (in any programming language). For lua see details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512778/why-does-lua-prohibit-goto-over-a-local-var-definition)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about it since I'm new in Lua, but I've heard about some using issues of `goto` in C too.